# SQL Server 2012 - Auto Increment and Null / Not Null

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created the following table for apartments and used auto-increment on column ApartmentID. I thought once I set this auto-increment to 101, it would automatically increase in the rows as I insert, however I just get a null value.

My Create table code is;
CREATE TABLE Apartments
(
ApartmentID smallint,--AUTOINCREMENT = 101,
Occupier smallint NULL default 0,
Rent money default 0,
CurrentOccupier smallint NULL,
)

Because I have auto increment included in my create table, I insert values as follows;
INSERT INTO dbo.Apartments (Occupier, Rent, CurrentOccupier)
VALUES
('1','400','21'),
('0','450','90'),

The following is my result;
ApartmentID     Occupier    Rent    CurrentOccupier
NULL        1       400.00      21
NULL        0       450.00      90

Concerned that the ApartmentID column was showing NULL instead of 101, 102, 103 etc and thinking this was to do with the column property null, I dropped the table an recreated it at follows;

CREATE TABLE Apartments
(
ApartmentID  smallint NOT NULL,--AUTOINCREMENT = 101,
Occupier smallint NULL default 0,
Rent money default 0,
CurrentOccupier  smallint NULL,
)

The result / message I got was 
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ApartmentID', table 'Apartment_2.dbo.Apartments'; column does not
allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I would like to work with the first table I created, if I could get the values 101, 102 etc to show up in the column ApartmentID, when I run the query select * from Apartments instead of the word null.

Any / advice help would be appreciated. Again it may be a simple error, but being new I do not recognize my error. Also I have included -- infront of auto increment, as I have seen that online.

Thanks
Josie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you declare the column as `IDENTITY` not autoincrement. The syntax to declare such a column seeded at 101 is

```
CREATE TABLE Apartments 
( 
ApartmentID smallint NOT NULL IDENTITY(101,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
Occupier smallint NOT NULL default 0, 
Rent money NOT NULL default 0, 
CurrentOccupier smallint NULL
)
```

I assumed that likely you will want this column to be the primary key. Remove those keywords if this is not the case.

Comment: @Martin.....Thank you for that. But my next question then becomes, why does identity column work and the auto-increment not work? Should they both not give the same result?

Comment: @Josie SQL Server doesn't use that `autoincrement` syntax. That is MySQL. They are different products and use different dialects of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. This should help you.

```
CREATE TABLE Apartments ( ApartmentID smallint IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL, Occupier smallint NULL default 0, Rent money default 0, CurrentOccupier smallint NULL);
```